VSCode - show `Terminal` by default rather than `Output`
By default, when I type ctrl+j or click a button in the status bar, the Output window opens, but I want to see the Terminal window:

How can I configure it to see by default Terminal in both cases: on status bar button click and ctrl+j typing?

Ctrl + will openTerminalas selected. FYICtrl+jor click on bar button will just toggle panel visibility. If you have selected tab asTERMINALbefore you hide given panel then it will reopen withTERMINAL` as selected tab.

BTW you can check and customize keyboard shortcuts from File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts.

Does this answer your question? How can I change keyboard shortcut bindings in Visual Studio Code?

@Karan yes but it does not solves the problem. Given answers  work only for ctrl+j but when I restart VSCode and click on status bar button, it still shows Output

STEP 1: Open the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) 
STEP 2: Choose Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)
STEP 3: Add the new rule in keybindings.json opened
{
  "key": "ctrl+j",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.toggleTerminal"
}



Your answer works only for ctrl+j but when I restart VSCode and click on status bar button, it still shows Output
